# Pandas/Sklearn gives incorrect Memoryerror

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, anaconda, jupyter

I'm working in Python2.7 (Anaconda 4.0) on a Jupyter notebook on a EC2 instance with plenty of memory (60GB, 48GB free according to `free`). I've loaded a Pandas (v0.18) dataframe that is large (150K rows, ~30KB per row), but is nowhere near the memory capacity of the instance, even if many many copies are made. Certain Pandas and Scikit-learn (v0.17) calls will trigger a MemoryError instantly, e.g.:

```
#X is a subset of the original df with 60 columns instead of the 3000
#Y is a float column
X.add(Y)

#And for sklearn...
pca = decomposition.KernelPCA(n_components=5)
pca.fit(X,Y)
```

Meanwhile, these work fine:

```
Z = X.copy(deep=True)
pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=5)
```

Most perplexingly, I can do this and it finishes in a few seconds:

```
huge = range(1000000000)
```

I've rebooted the notebook, the kernel, and the instance, but the same calls keep giving the `MemoryError`. I've also verified that I'm using 64-bit Python. Any suggestions?

Update: adding the traceback errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-9-ae71777140e2>", line 2, in <module>
    Z = X.add(Y)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 1057, in f
    return self._combine_series(other, na_op, fill_value, axis, level)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3500, in _combine_series
    fill_value=fill_value)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3528, in _combine_match_columns
    copy=False)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2730, in align
    broadcast_axis=broadcast_axis)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4152, in align
    fill_axis=fill_axis)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4234, in _align_series
    fdata = fdata.reindex_indexer(join_index, lidx, axis=0)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3528, in reindex_indexer
    fill_tuple=(fill_value,))
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3591, in _slice_take_blocks_ax0
    fill_value=fill_value))
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3621, in _make_na_block
    block_values = np.empty(block_shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-13-d510bc16443e>", line 3, in <module>
    pca.fit(X,Y)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/kernel_pca.py", line 202, in fit
    K = self._get_kernel(X)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/kernel_pca.py", line 135, in _get_kernel
    filter_params=True, **params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1347, in pairwise_kernels
    return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1054, in _parallel_pairwise
    return func(X, Y, **kwds)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 716, in linear_kernel
    return safe_sparse_dot(X, Y.T, dense_output=True)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 184, in safe_sparse_dot
    return fast_dot(a, b)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Things can grow large inside sklearn. What does `htop` show when the fitting is actually running?

Comment: can you put in a full stack trace?

Comment: It doesn't show the Python process at all. When I called the billion list, it started eating up the CPU and gradually using more memory. But these operations don't even make a blip, and they hit the error as soon as I run them.

Comment: @reptilicus just added.

Comment: Not sure, I'm guessing that somewhere in there, there is a huge array trying to get instantiated. Try to use a smaller batch size and see what happens.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html

Comment: @reptilicus, just took slearn out of the script (didn't even import) and the column add still fails. Looks like a Pandas issue.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the Pandas side of the issue. I had a DF and a Series with matching indexes, X and Y. I figured I could add Y as another column like this:

```
X.add(Y)
```

But doing this tries to match Y on the columns, not on the index, thus creating a 150Kx150K array. I needed to supply the axis:

```
X.add(Y, axis='index')
```